# elasticsearch aggregations out of memory on small subset of large index

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index called 'reporting', where we store different types of daily stats for each one of our  users. We have around 2,000 users. Our index is about 200million documents @ 40gb in size. We perform aggregations on this index for a given user's stats over a date-range.

In this case, we are performing a filtered 'bool' query and doing a terms match to filter by user id's (1 to 2 user-id's at a time) and a range match to filter by the date range. We have a bucket aggregation that groups them by user-id and a sub-aggregation that sums a single value for each bucket.

It kind of looks like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "terms": {
                                "uid": [1,2,3]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "d": {
                                    "gte": "2014-10-01",
                                    "lte": "2014-10-12"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "group_by_user": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "uid",
                "size": 0
            },
            "aggs": {
                "spend": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "sp"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is I'm hitting a circuit-breaker exception while running out of memory.
`[Data too large, data for field [uid] would be larger than limit of [2802686361/2.6gb]];`

We are running this on a 3 node cluster with 7.5gb of memory for each node; I can't help but feel like I'm doing something wrong with the query/filter. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Edit: Adding output of _stats

```
{
    "_shards": {
        "total": 6,
        "successful": 6,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "_all": {
        "primaries": {
            "docs": {
                "count": 212102401,
                "deleted": 318328
            },
            "store": {
                "size_in_bytes": 46498616525,
                "throttle_time_in_millis": 94162
            },
            "indexing": {
                "index_total": 9405119,
                "index_time_in_millis": 3091378,
                "index_current": 0,
                "delete_total": 0,
                "delete_time_in_millis": 0,
                "delete_current": 0
            },
            "get": {
                "total": 2,
                "time_in_millis": 22,
                "exists_total": 0,
                "exists_time_in_millis": 0,
                "missing_total": 2,
                "missing_time_in_millis": 22,
                "current": 0
            },
            "search": {
                "open_contexts": 0,
                "query_total": 1611,
                "query_time_in_millis": 489683,
                "query_current": 0,
                "fetch_total": 56,
                "fetch_time_in_millis": 62,
                "fetch_current": 0
            },
            "merges": {
                "current": 0,
                "current_docs": 0,
                "current_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "total": 831,
                "total_time_in_millis": 1228785,
                "total_docs": 33098268,
                "total_size_in_bytes": 7812950398
            },
            "refresh": {
                "total": 4978,
                "total_time_in_millis": 358409
            },
            "flush": {
                "total": 29,
                "total_time_in_millis": 8926
            },
            "warmer": {
                "current": 0,
                "total": 10852,
                "total_time_in_millis": 2293
            },
            "filter_cache": {
                "memory_size_in_bytes": 613970692,
                "evictions": 33934
            },
            "id_cache": {
                "memory_size_in_bytes": 0
            },
            "fielddata": {
                "memory_size_in_bytes": 4045281152,
                "evictions": 0
            },
            "percolate": {
                "total": 0,
                "time_in_millis": 0,
                "current": 0,
                "memory_size_in_bytes": -1,
                "memory_size": "-1b",
                "queries": 0
            },
            "completion": {
                "size_in_bytes": 0
            },
            "segments": {
                "count": 95,
                "memory_in_bytes": 1671534384,
                "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 0
            },
            "translog": {
                "operations": 436449,
                "size_in_bytes": 59595977
            },
            "suggest": {
                "total": 0,
                "time_in_millis": 0,
                "current": 0
            }
        },
        "total": {
            "docs": {
                "count": 424204629,
                "deleted": 685198
            },
            "store": {
                "size_in_bytes": 93177256029,
                "throttle_time_in_millis": 1609799
            },
            "indexing": {
                "index_total": 86978099,
                "index_time_in_millis": 31607032,
                "index_current": 0,
                "delete_total": 0,
                "delete_time_in_millis": 0,
                "delete_current": 0
            },
            "get": {
                "total": 4,
                "time_in_millis": 46,
                "exists_total": 0,
                "exists_time_in_millis": 0,
                "missing_total": 4,
                "missing_time_in_millis": 46,
                "current": 0
            },
            "search": {
                "open_contexts": 0,
                "query_total": 4674,
                "query_time_in_millis": 766372,
                "query_current": 0,
                "fetch_total": 114,
                "fetch_time_in_millis": 133,
                "fetch_current": 0
            },
            "merges": {
                "current": 0,
                "current_docs": 0,
                "current_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "total": 7700,
                "total_time_in_millis": 19175664,
                "total_docs": 358907679,
                "total_size_in_bytes": 82787257943
            },
            "refresh": {
                "total": 34174,
                "total_time_in_millis": 3192066
            },
            "flush": {
                "total": 175,
                "total_time_in_millis": 83934
            },
            "warmer": {
                "current": 0,
                "total": 76291,
                "total_time_in_millis": 29435
            },
            "filter_cache": {
                "memory_size_in_bytes": 1244975360,
                "evictions": 79602
            },
            "id_cache": {
                "memory_size_in_bytes": 0
            },
            "fielddata": {
                "memory_size_in_bytes": 8267198587,
                "evictions": 0
            },
            "percolate": {
                "total": 0,
                "time_in_millis": 0,
                "current": 0,
                "memory_size_in_bytes": -1,
                "memory_size": "-1b",
                "queries": 0
            },
            "completion": {
                "size_in_bytes": 0
            },
            "segments": {
                "count": 192,
                "memory_in_bytes": 3333325472,
                "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 0
            },
            "translog": {
                "operations": 876208,
                "size_in_bytes": 59595977
            },
            "suggest": {
                "total": 0,
                "time_in_millis": 0,
                "current": 0
            }
        }
    },
    "indices": {
        "reporting-stats": {
            "primaries": {
                "docs": {
                    "count": 212102401,
                    "deleted": 318328
                },
                "store": {
                    "size_in_bytes": 46498616525,
                    "throttle_time_in_millis": 94162
                },
                "indexing": {
                    "index_total": 9405119,
                    "index_time_in_millis": 3091378,
                    "index_current": 0,
                    "delete_total": 0,
                    "delete_time_in_millis": 0,
                    "delete_current": 0
                },
                "get": {
                    "total": 2,
                    "time_in_millis": 22,
                    "exists_total": 0,
                    "exists_time_in_millis": 0,
                    "missing_total": 2,
                    "missing_time_in_millis": 22,
                    "current": 0
                },
                "search": {
                    "open_contexts": 0,
                    "query_total": 1611,
                    "query_time_in_millis": 489683,
                    "query_current": 0,
                    "fetch_total": 56,
                    "fetch_time_in_millis": 62,
                    "fetch_current": 0
                },
                "merges": {
                    "current": 0,
                    "current_docs": 0,
                    "current_size_in_bytes": 0,
                    "total": 831,
                    "total_time_in_millis": 1228785,
                    "total_docs": 33098268,
                    "total_size_in_bytes": 7812950398
                },
                "refresh": {
                    "total": 4978,
                    "total_time_in_millis": 358409
                },
                "flush": {
                    "total": 29,
                    "total_time_in_millis": 8926
                },
                "warmer": {
                    "current": 0,
                    "total": 10852,
                    "total_time_in_millis": 2293
                },
                "filter_cache": {
                    "memory_size_in_bytes": 613970692,
                    "evictions": 33934
                },
                "id_cache": {
                    "memory_size_in_bytes": 0
                },
                "fielddata": {
                    "memory_size_in_bytes": 4045281152,
                    "evictions": 0
                },
                "percolate": {
                    "total": 0,
                    "time_in_millis": 0,
                    "current": 0,
                    "memory_size_in_bytes": -1,
                    "memory_size": "-1b",
                    "queries": 0
                },
                "completion": {
                    "size_in_bytes": 0
                },
                "segments": {
                    "count": 95,
                    "memory_in_bytes": 1671534384,
                    "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                    "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 0
                },
                "translog": {
                    "operations": 436449,
                    "size_in_bytes": 59595977
                },
                "suggest": {
                    "total": 0,
                    "time_in_millis": 0,
                    "current": 0
                }
            },
            "total": {
                "docs": {
                    "count": 424204629,
                    "deleted": 685198
                },
                "store": {
                    "size_in_bytes": 93177256029,
                    "throttle_time_in_millis": 1609799
                },
                "indexing": {
                    "index_total": 86978099,
                    "index_time_in_millis": 31607032,
                    "index_current": 0,
                    "delete_total": 0,
                    "delete_time_in_millis": 0,
                    "delete_current": 0
                },
                "get": {
                    "total": 4,
                    "time_in_millis": 46,
                    "exists_total": 0,
                    "exists_time_in_millis": 0,
                    "missing_total": 4,
                    "missing_time_in_millis": 46,
                    "current": 0
                },
                "search": {
                    "open_contexts": 0,
                    "query_total": 4674,
                    "query_time_in_millis": 766372,
                    "query_current": 0,
                    "fetch_total": 114,
                    "fetch_time_in_millis": 133,
                    "fetch_current": 0
                },
                "merges": {
                    "current": 0,
                    "current_docs": 0,
                    "current_size_in_bytes": 0,
                    "total": 7700,
                    "total_time_in_millis": 19175664,
                    "total_docs": 358907679,
                    "total_size_in_bytes": 82787257943
                },
                "refresh": {
                    "total": 34174,
                    "total_time_in_millis": 3192066
                },
                "flush": {
                    "total": 175,
                    "total_time_in_millis": 83934
                },
                "warmer": {
                    "current": 0,
                    "total": 76291,
                    "total_time_in_millis": 29435
                },
                "filter_cache": {
                    "memory_size_in_bytes": 1244975360,
                    "evictions": 79602
                },
                "id_cache": {
                    "memory_size_in_bytes": 0
                },
                "fielddata": {
                    "memory_size_in_bytes": 8267198587,
                    "evictions": 0
                },
                "percolate": {
                    "total": 0,
                    "time_in_millis": 0,
                    "current": 0,
                    "memory_size_in_bytes": -1,
                    "memory_size": "-1b",
                    "queries": 0
                },
                "completion": {
                    "size_in_bytes": 0
                },
                "segments": {
                    "count": 192,
                    "memory_in_bytes": 3333325472,
                    "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                    "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 0
                },
                "translog": {
                    "operations": 876208,
                    "size_in_bytes": 59595977
                },
                "suggest": {
                    "total": 0,
                    "time_in_millis": 0,
                    "current": 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the mapping for field "d"? this could be due to the range filter just for debugging try doing the same query with a "and" filter instead of top level bool.

Comment: the date range returns the correct range, but I'll definitely give the and filter a try in a minute.

edit: the 'd' field mapping is
`d: {
type: "date",
format: "dateOptionalTime"
}`

Comment: sorry probably should have mentioned before did you try the index stats and could you paste it .
curl -XGET "http://<server>/reporting/_stats?"

Comment: @keety I've updated the q to add the output of _stats

Comment: bit of shot in the dark the fielddata cache looks really large you could use the following to check the fielddata cache per field http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-stats.html#field-data  and check how much uid takes up , long shot you could do a clear cache  http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-clearcache.html#indices-clearcache and check running the query again (note clear cache is not immediate and you got to wait a couple of minutes for the cache to clear)

Comment: looks like it is the fielddata cache; I'm doing some more homework on optimizing to solve this problem. I'm not sure how to keep the cache from filling up, I'm using a hosted service provider, so I'll definitely need to find a way to fix the query/filtering on my end to keep the cache size manageable. We have multiple types of stats built for each user and each stat has different fields and we aggregate each type of stat differently so there has to be a solution to balance the dynamics of our queries with the cache size and performance.